# Angular 4 - How to render childcomponents using bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular 4 component, AppComponent. This AppComponent renders a list of child components. I want this list of child components to be rendered in a bootstrap grid system. But it gives me some problems using angular 4.

The idea is like this (app.component.html):

```
<div class="container">
    <one-component [keyCode]="49"></one-component>
    <one-component [keyCode]="49"></one-component>
    <one-component [keyCode]="49"></one-component>
</div>
```

The one-component's html is simple and looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         Test {{keyCode}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But this code seems to ignore the bootstrap grid, the result is simply some stacked content that clearly is not using the grid.

Since i am new to angular 4/bootstrap i do not know if there is an angular-way to do this :)

Can someone tell me what i might be doing wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: It's because you create a new row for each component instance

Comment: I missed that one (event though it was very clear :D), thanks!